# Why does the node.js dialogflow sample code copy output contexts to input contexts?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es

In the sample code for [detecting intents from text](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/detect-intent-text), the node.js version copies the response-output-contexts into the request-input-contexts of the next request, however the other languages' samples omit that part. What is this context-copying good for?

Contexts are supposed to be kept alive for the specified `lifespanCount` requests by the agent anyhow, so I have trouble seeing the use for it. Or is it something required only for the older v1 API, not for the current v2 API?

Extracts from the sample code linked above:

```
// First query.
promise = sessionClient.detectIntent(request);

// and for the rest of the queries...
promise = promise.then(responses => {
  const response = responses[0];

  // Use output contexts as input contexts for the next query.
  request.queryParams = {
    contexts: response.queryResult.outputContexts,
  };

  return sessionClient.detectIntent(request);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that for a given conversation, the context is used to carry information from one intent to another. See [their documentation here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts).

I played around a bit with the API, and I was able to maintain a conversation even with the contexts not being set on the subsequent request.queryParams. After further experimentation, this seems possibly due to the use of a session identifier holding an implicit context (or maybe "last context"?). This is speculation, but personally I would adhere to the docs and always provide the contexts returned in the response for any subsequent requests.

I'm trying to prove it, but I think it's due to a session being able to contain multiple contexts at one time.

**UPDATE:**

Digging further into the reference, I did find this useful explanation: https://dialogflow.com/docs/contexts/input-output-contexts#input_contexts

> **Input contexts**
>
> When added to intents, *input contexts increase the likelihood of that intent being matched when that context is active.*
>
> While intents are matched when a user replies with something similar to defined training phrases, contexts attached to a session can force an intent to be matched.

Comment: Thanks @sean-aitken, I should have added explicitly that I already knew that contexts are associated with the session (identifier) in my original post to clarify, that's why I wonder about the node.js sample copying the contexts. The sample code already uses a `sessionId` variable for that.